# How do I handle an 'undefined' value in a json request in Jackson/SpringMVC?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

When I do a `POST` request to a `@RestController` like this:

`{ "name": undefined }`

I get the following response:

```
{
    ...
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
    "message": "Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'undefined': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5f9559a4; line: 3, column: 27]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'undefined': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5f9559a4; line: 3, column: 27]",
    ...
}
```

I'm looking for a general solution to tell jackson to always map/deserialize `undefined` as `null`. I haven't found a single example or documentation that refers to handling undefined values so any pointers would be apreciated.

Comment: `undefined` is not a valid JSON literal.

Comment: The question is: Is there a way to map it to a valid JSON literal like `null`?

Comment: I wouldn't count on it. Jackson is designed to parse JSON, not a JSON-like syntax that isn't exactly JSON due to the `undefined` token.

Comment: Jackson is not designed to parse "ONLY" JSON it can parse many different formats. And it has options like ignoring properties when it doesn't recognize the value, I'm looking for something similar but to ignore the value when deserializing, not the property when serializing. It also has a way to use Custom Deserializers, but the examples I've seen are done in each class, I wonder if there's a more general solution, like a default custom deserializer for all classes or something.

Comment: I agree with @hexafraction here, you must concentrate on fixing the problem where it is generating this invalid json it is most likely an js error.

Comment: @Langley: saw your comment about the focus being an `undefined` value. In that case, I am going to remove my answer, because it doesn't really apply to your question.

Comment: np, Thanks @SeanMickey

Answer (score 1):

### The Real Answer

Dont send undefined.

### Bad Answer

Define the value as a String in your target object then wrap it in methods.  Perhaps, something like this:

```
private String blammy;

public boolean isBlammyTrue()
{
    return "true".equalsIgnoreCase(blammy);
}

public boolean isBlammyFalse()
{
    return !isBlammyTrue();
}
```